# Assigning Values to a Class Property in PHP

Tags: php, properties

One of the examples in the PHP book I am learning from (illustrating private properties) starts like this:

```
class Account {
   private $_totalBalance = 0;

   public function makeDeposit($amount) {
      $this->_totalBalance+= $amount;
   }

   public function makeWithdrawal ($amount){
      if ($amount < $this->_totalBalance) {
         $this->_totalBalance -= $amount;
      }
      else {
         die("insufficient funds <br />" );
      }
   }
   public function getTotalBalance() {
      return $this->_totalBalance;
   }
}

$a = new Account;
$a->makeDeposit(500);
$a->makeWithdrawal(100);
echo $a->getTotalBalance();
$a->makeWithdrawal(1000);
?>
```

My question is, why is the $_totalBalance property assigned a value in the class rather than the object?  Wouldn't you want the value of $totalBalance to be specific to an object?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What makes you think it's assigned in the class rather than the object?  In your example, you only create one instance.

Comment: what do you mean ?! the value is assigned to `$this->_totalBalance`, and `$this` is the object.

Comment: `die()` shouldn't be used in a class, it defeats the purpose of encapsulation. Throw an exception instead.

Comment: but it has a beginning balance of 0, right? private $_totalBalance = 0.  what im unclear about is why there is a value (0), inside the class.

Comment: @user It's a default value to be set upon instantiation. You could do the same thing in the constructor, eg `public function __construct() { $this->_totalBalance = 0; }`

Comment: ok, so all objects would start with the same $_totalBalance?  If I were to create a new object ($b), it would also start with a total balance of 0?

Answer (score -1):

When you call `$a->makeDeposit()`, inside makeDeposit() `$this` is the same as `$a`.  If you had another instance (`$b = new Account;`) then calling `$b->makeDeposit()` would mean `$this` would be the same as `$b`.

Comment: Err, class and object are most certainly not interchangeable. A class is a definition whereas an object is an instance of a class.

Comment: That's true, but 'object' is often used to mean something other than 'instance', so I don't think it's the most descriptive term to use.

Comment: `Account` most certainly is NOT both class and object.

Comment: Fine, I'll remove that bit.  I always called things other than classes objects, and according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29) this was common before object-oriented programming became widely used...